# Undeclare a Record with only Site collecton admin rights

Tags: powershell, read-only, record

Sharepoint Online: I have a problem with a list item that was declared as record but now is impossible to undeclare. Despite I am the Site Collection Amdinistrator, when  going to Compliance Details and clicking on *undeclare*, I have to result and after 2-3 seconds of *processing request...* the status is again on *record*. 
Unfortunately I have no way to get higher permissions - so I cannot use powershell to do it. Does anybody have a suggestion or a workaround?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very very strange... after a while (about **3 hours**, but the item was set as record 8 days ago), it was again possible to undeclare it!
I am working on Sharepoint Online for a big ONG, and cannot tell the details of the subscription. 
Anyway it seems that **there was some bug at MS level**.
Hope it was useful to somebody else too.